# error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition, while installing npm modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install npm modules using `npm install`, while doing so I'm getting error in console saying error:

```
node_modules\msgpack\deps\msgpack\msgpack\sysdep.h(24): error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types

d:\sagews\hermes-hen-scv-android\node_modules\grunt-html-builder\node_modules\msgpack\deps\msgpack\msgpack\sysdep.h(24): error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types
Project : warning PRJ0018: The following environment variables were not found:
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\SageWS\hermes-hen-scv-android\node_modules\grunt-html-builder\node_modules\msgpack
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.13
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.2
gyp ERR! not ok
unbuild msgpack@0.2.4
unbuild grunt-html-builder@0.5.8
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with compiling the `msgpack` library on Windows.  Have you checked the issue tracker for `msgpack` and `msgpack-node` to see if anyone else has reported this error?

You can verify that this is an error in `msgpack` by doing the following:

```
> cd C:\temp
> npm i msgpack
```

If that fails, then this is not a problem that `npm` can fix, and you'll have to go upstream.